# ob_end_flush() failed to delete and flush buffer

Tags: php, e-notices

Our code is this:

```
//configs
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('output_buffering', 1);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
```

This was programmed by a coder for us and it worked fine until a recent PHP upgrade.  The notice we are getting now is:

Notice:  ob_end_flush() failed to delete and flush buffer.  No buffer to delete or flush in ...

Is there a better way to code this or a proper way?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is that your entire PHP code?

Comment: output buffering -- why?

Comment: `ini_set('display)errors',1)` uh? where is the semicolon ? And why the strange bracket, typo?

Comment: No, that is just the beginning its a 16 page code but that is the only error and that is the BEGINNING of the code.  The first ini_set is wrapped tho on its own line.

Comment: There should be an ob_start()

Comment: ob_start(true); or just ob_start()  - thanks!!